# IE6: width or height set to 0px does not work when content inside

Tags: javascript, css

If I want to set `width` of a `div` containing some text and I want to set the `width` of that `div` to `0` in IE6 (I have not checked in IE7) does not work!!!

Please check the HTML below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        #box {
            width: 0px;
            background-color: blue;

        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="box"><span>hello</span></div>
    <script>
        $("#box").width(0);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The width of the `div` stuck to the minimum content width of the `div`.

Regards,
Munim

Comment: an easier approach would be to set display:hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I pointed out in the other answer, stuff that doesn't fit in the box will overflow the fixed size unless you hide it. If you can't use `overflow:hidden` then positioning is another way to do it:

```
<style>
#box {
  position: relative;
  width: 0; }
}
#box span {
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
}
</style>

<div id="box"><span>hello</span></div>
```

Any element that's positioned using `position:absolute` is taken out of the document flow and will not affect other elements, including the size of the container, which you can then size to the dimensions you need.

Comment: Thanks, yet cannot set width to 0

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow:hidden` if you need the contents to be cut off. Without it, the layout will consider the size of the box to be 0, but the content that doesn't fit will extend outside of its container.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your answer, I should have mentioned it that I have an element inside where I set the `left: - 20px` and if I set it to `overflow: hidden` then the element gets hidden. Can you please give me another solution than this. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want width and height to be 0, then `display:none` is the usual way to totally hide it.

Comment: Well, I can't use `display:none` as part of it is outside the `div` using `left: -20px`

Answer (score 1):

The actual div does have a width of 0 (you can tell if you put a border around it).  If you need the text inside the div to be hidden, but not the other element, I would suggest adding the following css:

```
#box span {
display: none;
}
```